# Trigonometric Identities//Fourier Series

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Basically I have to find the value of a constant $M$ from this equation: $$l(x)=0=\sum M\Big(\frac{n\pi}{L}\Big)\sin(n\pi x) $$
using the Fourier Series. However the usual Fourier Series formula is:
$$l(x)=a_0 + \sum a_n \cos \Big(\frac {n\pi x}{L}\Big) +b_n \sin \Big(\frac {n\pi x}{L}\Big) $$
So is it possible to express $\sin(n\pi x)$ as $\sin \big(\frac {n\pi x}{L}\big)$ or is there any other way?

Comment: What are $L$ and $M$?

Comment: @Farnight Oh sorry. L is a constant and M is a sequence to be determined by the Fourier Series

Comment: I don't get why you need the terms $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$. If $l$ is $0$, doesn't that mean that $M$ is $0$?

Comment: @Farnight this is actually a part of a pde problem. L is the domain in x: $0 < x < L$. I need to use the Fourier Series to express this constant M and I can't just say that its zero, though one could have guessed it. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: This is still unclear. First, you gave a definition for $l$ as a sum. If that sum is infinite, I don't think it converges in the first place. If it is finite, then it must be non zero for some $x$. So $M$ must be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $sin(m\pi x)$ and then integral over one period.

$$
\int _0^\frac{2}{m}l(x)\sin (m \pi x)dx = \int _0^\frac{2}{m} \sum_n M\frac{n\pi}{L}sin(n\pi x)sin(m \pi x)dx
$$
This integral on the right hand side is equal to zero for all $n$ except when $n=m$ where it is $\frac{M\pi}{L}$. So you have:
$$
M = \frac{L}{\pi}\int _0^\frac{2}{m}l(x)\sin (m \pi x)dx
$$